# Map Raggedly to Depth but Stop at Sentinel

Tags: r, purrr, traversal, rlang, package-development

## Motivation

I am developing an R package with an essential helper function "`make()`".  This `make()` function accepts a ragged list, then maps function `foo()` onto the *penultimate* nodes ("twigs") in the list: those whose children are leaves.  So far [`purrr::map_depth`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_if.html)`(..., .depth = -2, .ragged = TRUE)` seems ideal.

There is one catch: the traversal must stop at a node that is a [`done_box`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/done.html) — or some sentinel class of my own creation — *regardless of its depth*, even though that node is also (ie. inherits from) a `list` of arbitrary depth.  The function `foo()` will then map the node conditionally, based on its class.

### Challenge

Unfortunately, the inflexibility of [`purrr::vec_depth()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/vec_depth.html) induces an error when it encounters objective nodes:

```
Error in `.f()`:
! `x` must be a vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

---

## Bandaid Solution

As such, I have tentatively written a variation `.map_depth()` on the [source code for `map_depth()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/ae4d9ebdf1d2349ac17f590fc7f1ec0fef8c66a8/R/map.R#L285-L295), where `.list_depth()` replaces `vec_depth()` to handle objective nodes.  See the **Code** section for the code.

I can then create a sentinel class `my_sentinel`, which "boxes" (ie. wraps in a `list`) a [`quosure`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-quosure.html) for the `expression` that generates the node's value.  Since this `my_sentinel` inherits from `list`, then `.list_depth()` will give its `quosure` a depth of `1` and give the sentinel itself a depth of `2`.

At a `.depth` of `-2`, the `.map_depth()` function will thus target the `my_sentinel` node itself.  By design, `foo()` will identify its class as `"my_sentinel"`, and it will evaluate the `quosure` to "unbox" the value.

### Drawback

Unfortunately, the `environment` of the `quosure` may change since the `quosure` was first captured.  So when `.map_depth()` is finally called, it might "unbox" the wrong value: one that was wrongly updated.

As such, the behavior could prove unstable for end users!

---

## Question

Is there a cleaner or *canonical* way to `purrr::map_*()` a function `foo()` to the "twigs" (ie. nodes at `.depth = -2`) of a `list`, while stopping at nodes that are sentinel objects like `done_box`?

### Suggestion

I'm curious about [`purrr::map_if()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_if.html), with some predicate `.p` that tests for both class and depth.  However, I lack the expertise to confirm this as feasible, let alone *canonical*.

---

## Code

For `my_sentinel`:

```
my_sentinel <- function(x) {
  x_quo <- rlang::enquo0(x)
  
  # No pun intended.
  x_box <- list(x_quo)
  
  structure(x_box,
    class = c("my_sentinel", class(x_box))
  )
}
```

For `.map_depth()`:

```
# A variation on 'purrr::map_depth()' that accommodates objective leaves.
.map_depth <- function(.x, .depth, .f, ..., .ragged = FALSE) {
  if (!rlang::is_integerish(.depth, n = 1, finite = TRUE)) {
    abort("`.depth` must be a single number")
  }
  if (.depth < 0) {
    .depth <- .list_depth(.x) + .depth
  }
  .f <- purrr::as_mapper(.f, ...)
  .map_depth_rec(.x, .depth, .f, ..., .ragged = .ragged, .atomic = FALSE)
}


# A variation on 'purrr:::map_depth_rec()' that accommodates objective leaves.
.map_depth_rec <- function(.x, .depth, .f, ..., .ragged, .atomic) {
  if (.depth < 0) {
    rlang::abort("Invalid depth")
  }
  # TODO: Must this be addressed too (unlikely)?
  if (.atomic) {
    if (!.ragged) {
      rlang::abort("List not deep enough")
    }
    return(purrr::map(.x, .f, ...))
  }
  if (.depth == 0) {
    return(.f(.x, ...))
  }
  if (.depth == 1) {
    return(purrr::map(.x, .f, ...))
  }
  .atomic <- rlang::is_atomic(.x)
  purrr::map(.x, function(x) {
    .map_depth_rec(x, .depth - 1, .f, ..., .ragged = .ragged, 
                    .atomic = .atomic)
  })
}


# A variation on 'purrr::vec_depth()' that accommodates objective leaves.
.list_depth <- function(x) {
  if (rlang::is_null(x)) {
    0L
  }
  # TODO: Address this so a vector is treated as a leaf (or must users esc() for that?).
  else if (rlang::is_atomic(x)) {
    1L
  }
  else if (rlang::is_list(x)) {
    depths <- purrr::map_int(x, .list_depth)
    1L + max(depths, 0L)
  }
  # Accommodate objective leaves.
  else if (is.object(x)) {
    # TODO: Check if this should be 1L or (as I suspect) 0L!
    1L
  }
  else {
    rlang::abort("`x` must be a vector or an object")
  }
}
```

Comment: **Update**: Looks like [`purrr::map_if()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_if.html) is the way to go, with a predicate `.p = ~.list_depth(.) == 2 || inherits(., "my_sentinel")` to test the class, and `.f = foo` to map it.  Or perhaps a modification to `.list_depth()` that returns `2L` when the object is a `my_sentinel`, which simplifies the predicate to `.p = ~.list_depth(.) == 2`.

Comment: The only issue is this: how much _performance_ do I sacrifice, by making `map_if()` check *every* node with `.p`, rather than some alternative with `map_depth()` that targets only one level?

Answer (score 1):

Just mentioning `rrapply()` in package `rrapply` (an extended version of base `rapply`), which may already provide the functionality you are looking for.

Using the following dummy list, since no data is provided in the question:

```
## dummy data
l <- list(
  list("initial_node"),
  list(list("initial_node")),
  structure(list("initial_node"), class = c("list", "my_sentinal")),
  structure(list(list("initial_node")), class = c("list", "my_sentinal"))
)
```

In a first call, the `my_sentinal` class is recursively propagated to each sublist. In a second call, some function `f` is applied to all lists with no sublists that do not inherit from the `my_sentinal` class. NB: this can probably be combined into a single call with some effort, but split into two separate calls the code is likely easier to follow and understand.

```
## propagate my_sentinal class to deeper sublists
l1 <- rrapply(
  l, 
  classes ="list",
  condition = \(x) inherits(x, "my_sentinal"),
  f = \(x) {
    if(is.list(x[[1]])) x[] <- lapply(x, structure, class = c("list", "my_sentinal"))
    return(x)
  },
  how = "recurse"
)

## apply function to non-sentinal pen-ultimate nodes 
l2 <- rrapply(
  l1, 
  classes = "list",
  condition = \(x) !inherits(x, "my_sentinal") && !is.list(x[[1]]),
  f = \(x) lapply(x, \(xi) "processed_node")
)

str(l2)
#> List of 4
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "processed_node"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "processed_node"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "initial_node"
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "my_sentinal"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "initial_node"
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "my_sentinal"
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "my_sentinal"
```

Disclaimer: I am also the maintainer of the `rrapply`-package.